# Python win32api mouse control losing focus

Tags: python, winapi

I'm using win32api in a Python script to control mouse movements. It's working fantastic, but as soon as I click (I also generate click events) outside my Python shell/IDE, all my mouse events immediately stop. If I click my shell/IDE again, control is restored.

It seems like mouse control is only working when my Python shell or IDE is the "active" window - is there any way to retain mouse control even after Python is sent to the background?

Comment: Can you share your script please?

Comment: I don't have access to it now, but there's nothing particularly special about it - it just calls win32api.SetCursorPos(x,y). I've also tried win32api.mouse_event(...), but both stop working as soon as I click outside of the Python shell.

If it helps any, I'm just doing an infinite while loop in which I run some calculations and do some mouse movements. There's no control-passing going on, it's very straightforward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was not a Python issue, but was an issue with the device I was using to generate mouse movements. A separate API call was required to allow this device to push events when its owner was out of focus.